# CMake + Qt : define the moc/ui output directory

Tags: qt, qt4, cmake, moc

I'm currently transferring a project built with qmake to CMake.

In the version with qmake, in the .pri file, there was

```
MOC_DIR = .moc/$${PLATFORM_NAME}
```

that permitted to produce the MOC temporary files in a given directory, keeping the sources clean. How to do the same thing with CMake?

Note: with CMake, I use the `FindQt4.cmake` package and the command `QT4_WRAP_CPP()`.

Comment: Generally, you use an out-of-tree build to keep your sources clean. See http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As baysmith says, if your goal is to keep your source directory clean, the real solution is to use CMake's ["out-of-source"](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees) builds feature. If you're on Windows, set "Where to build the binaries" to a new directory, different from the "Where is the source code" directory. If you're on Unix, it goes something like this:

```
cd <source directory>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

By running CMake on a different directory, all of the build files will go into that directory, and your sources will stay clean. (Note: the build directory doesn't have to be inside the source directory. See the [CMake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees) for more details.)

If "out-of-source" doesn't work for you, I was able to find one other option. Based on what I can tell from the `Qt4Macros.cmake` file installed with my CMake 2.8, it isn't accessible as a config parameter. Here's the relevant line:

```
SET(_moc    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_current_MOC})
```

The workaround is to change all of your MOC include directives to specify the subfolder you'd like to build to.

```
#include "moc/mainwindow.moc"
```

After creating the `moc` directory inside my build directory, there were no problems building, and my MOC file was in the new directory.